# Trying to justify a step in a proof for calculating Galois groups

Tags: galois-theory

I’ve been making my way through *A Course in Galois Theory* by Garling.

For those who have the book, I’m trying to justify a step in the middle of p. 157 for a proof of a theorem that leads to an algorithm for calculating Galois groups.  As Garling points out, the algorithm is too computational, and it is more theoretical than practical.  Anyway, I hope I can get help justifying the step, described below.

For those who don’t have the book, I'll try to distill out the exact part I can’t get through:

Let

$\beta = \alpha_1 x_1 + \alpha_2 x_2 + … + \alpha_n x_n$

For $\sigma \in \Sigma_n$, define $\sigma_x$ to permute the $x_i$ and define $\sigma_\alpha$ to permute the $\alpha_i$.

So

$\sigma_x(\beta) = \alpha_1 x_{\sigma(1)} + \alpha_2 x_{\sigma(2)} + … + \alpha_n x_{\sigma(n)}$

and

$\sigma_\alpha(\beta) = \alpha_{\sigma(1)} x_1 + \alpha_{\sigma(2)} x_2 + … + \alpha_{\sigma(n)} x_n$

Here is the step to justify:

$\prod_{\sigma \in A_1} (y - \tau_x \sigma_x(\beta)) = \prod_{\sigma \in A_1} (y - (\tau^{-1})_\alpha \sigma_x(\beta))$

where $A_1$ is a subgroup of $\Sigma_n$, and $\tau \in \Sigma_n$.

I see that:

$\tau_x \sigma_x(\beta) = \alpha_1 x_{\tau \sigma (1)} + \alpha_2 x_{\tau \sigma (2)} + … + \alpha_n x_{\tau \sigma (n)}$

and

$\begin{align}
(\tau^{-1})_\alpha \sigma_x(\beta) & = \alpha_{\tau^{-1}(1)} x_{\sigma(1)} + \alpha_{\tau^{-1}(2)} x_{\sigma(2)} + … + \alpha_{\tau^{-1}(n)} x_{\sigma(n)} \\
& = \alpha_{\tau^{-1} (\tau (1))} x_{\sigma (\tau (1))} + \alpha_{\tau^{-1} (\tau (2))} x_{\sigma (\tau (2))} + … + \alpha_{\tau^{-1} (\tau (n))} x_{\sigma (\tau (n))} \\
& = \alpha_1 x_{\sigma \tau (1)} + \alpha_2 x_{\sigma \tau (2)} + … + \alpha_n x_{\sigma \tau (n)} \\
& = \sigma_x \tau_x(\beta)
\end{align}$

But these do not seem to be equal.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: It doesn't say that $\tau_x\sigma_x(\beta) = (\tau^{-1})_\alpha \sigma_x(\beta)$, but instead that the products are equal. What you need to show is that there is a bijection $A_1 \to A_1$ which carries each $\sigma$ to some $\sigma'$ such that $\tau_x\sigma_x(\beta) = (\tau^{-1})_\alpha\sigma'_x(\beta)$.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair - Thanks. Unfortunately, it isn't clear to me now what the bijection would be. Like $\sigma \mapsto \sigma^{-1}$ won't work.

I was hoping just mentioning $A_1$ is a subgroup would be enough to get an answer. Maybe I need to provide the exact subgroup, but it is hard to distill out $A_1$ without going into all the details in the book.

Comment: You are not trying to guess a bijection. You just need to show that one exists. Every $\alpha$ coefficient occurs once in $\tau_x\sigma_x(\beta)$, and each also occurs once in $(\tau^{-1})_\alpha\sigma'_x(\beta)$, though in a different order. But the summation doesn't depend on the order of the terms. You want to define $\sigma'$ so that the same $x_i$ is multiplied by that $\alpha$ coefficient on each side.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair - Thanks again.  As you probably noticed, I posted an alternative answer below.  Does it look correct?  I'll think about a direct answer, based on your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm going to post the following as an answer because, if correct, it'll get me through to complete the proof, as an alternative approach. Please check my answer.  Also, maybe with the extra details, someone can post a direct answer that justifies the step.

In the book, the first part of the proof showed that $A_1 \subseteq \Gamma_K(L)$. The second part, which includes the step I couldn't justify, shows $\Gamma_K(L) \subseteq A_1$.  Here now is my attempt to show the second part.

To start, let me provide the following two details, and then I'll proceed from there.

$L = K(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, … , \alpha_n)$, where $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, … , \alpha_n$ distinct roots

and

$\prod_{\sigma \in A_1} (y - \sigma_x(\beta)) = F_1 \in K[y, x_1, x_2, … , x_n]$

Note that

$ F_1 = \prod_{\sigma \in A_1} (y - (\sigma^{-1})_\alpha (\beta)) = \prod_{\sigma \in A_1} (y - \sigma_\alpha (\beta))$

Consider

$\tau \in \Gamma_K(L)$

Then

$F_1 = \tau(F_1) = \tau_\alpha(\prod_{\sigma \in A_1} (y - \sigma_\alpha (\beta))) = \prod_{\sigma \in A_1} (y - \tau_\alpha \sigma_\alpha (\beta))$

Matching up the above factorizations for $F_1$, we must have

$\tau_\alpha \sigma_\alpha' = e_\alpha$ for some $\sigma' \in A_1$

So

$\tau = \sigma'^{-1} \in A_1$

Comment: Since I do not have that book, I do not know its notations. What is $\Gamma_K(L)$? And why is $F_1 = \tau(F_1)$? Have you proven at this point that factorization is unique over $K(\alpha_1, ...)$?

Comment: @Paul Sinclair - $\Gamma_K(L)$ is the Galois group of $L:K$.  Maybe I am not using exactly the right notation, and it should be $\Gamma(L : K)$ or $\Gamma_K(f)$, where $f \in K[x]$ with distinct roots $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, ..., \alpha_n \in L$.  Since $\tau \in \Gamma(L : K)$ fixes $K$, $\tau(F_1) = F_1$.  Also, $K[y, x_1, x_2, ..., x_n]$ is a UFD since $K$ is a field.